SwiftUI / Can't save Picker timer
I can't save the selected timer value after leaving View.
Briefly: the user enters the screen, selects the timer time, clicks save, the selected value is saved in UserDefaults. Then the person leaves the screen (via the cross at the top). When he returns to the timer view - there should be the last set value from UserDefaults.
Timer model code:
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class TimerSettings: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var selectedTime: Int?
    
    init(initialSelectedTime: Int?) {
        self.selectedTime = initialSelectedTime
    }
    func saveSettings(time: Int, forKey: String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(time, forKey: forKey)
        print(time)
    }
    func loadSettings(forKey: String) -> Int? {
        if let savedSettings = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: forKey) as? Int {
            selectedTime = savedSettings
            return savedSettings
        } else {
            selectedTime = nil
            return nil
        }
    }
}

TimerView code:
import SwiftUI

struct TimerView: View {

    @StateObject var timerSettings = TimerSettings(initialSelectedTime: nil)

    @State var selectedTime = 3
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Change time:")
                    .foregroundStyle(Color(.black).opacity(0.8))
                Picker("Timer", selection: $selectedTime) {
                    ForEach(1..<31, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0) min").tag($0)
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                Button("Save") {
                
                    timerSettings.saveSettings(time: selectedTime, forKey: "timerSettings")
                    
                }
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .padding(.bottom, 100)
                .onAppear {
                    timerSettings.loadSettings(forKey: "timerSettings")!
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red:0.8980392157, green: 0.9333333333, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    CustomBackButtonView()
                }
            }
        }
    }

#Preview {
    TimerView()
}


Why not use @AppStorage instead? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage

Otherwise don't use a @State property in the view and use the published property in TimerSettings directly instead.

I’m just learning sui and it’s still difficult to figure out property wrappers, if you tell me how, I’ll try to do it

I'll try to figure out how AppStorage works, thanks

I got help with a solution:
So, Timer settings without any changes:
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class TimerSettings: ObservableObject {

    @Published var selectedTime: Int?

    init(initialSelectedTime: Int?) {
        self.selectedTime = initialSelectedTime
    }
    //униварсальная функция сохранения
    func saveSettings(time: Int, forKey: String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(time, forKey: forKey)
        print(time)
    }
    //универсальная функция загрузки
    func loadSettings(forKey: String) -> Int? {
        if let savedSettings = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: forKey) as? Int {
            selectedTime = savedSettings
            return savedSettings
        } else {
            selectedTime = nil
            return nil
        }
    }
}

And only one thing on View in .onAppear:
 import SwiftUI
    
    struct TimerView: View {
    
        @State var timerSettings = TimerSettings(initialSelectedTime: nil)
    
        @State var selectedTime = 0
        @State var mainTime = 3
    
        var body: some View {
                VStack {
                    Text("Настройте таймер игры:")
                        .foregroundStyle(Color(.black).opacity(0.8))
                    Picker("Время таймера", selection: $mainTime) {
                        ForEach(1..<31, id: \.self) {
                            Text("\($0) мин").tag($0)
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    Button("Сохранить") {
                        selectedTime = mainTime
                        timerSettings.saveSettings(time: selectedTime, forKey: "timerSettings")
                    }
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .padding(.bottom, 100)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    mainTime = timerSettings.loadSettings(forKey: "timerSettings")!
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red:0.8980392157, green: 0.9333333333, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        CustomBackButtonView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    #Preview {
        TimerView()
    }


It's your choice but I don't understand why you choose this overly complicated solution with an extra class and 2(!) @State properties to keep track of one value instead of using @AppStorage.

hi, I think the main reason is because I’m just learning, it looks more clear to me, to be honest, I don’t know why :D

By your code, it is storing the selectedTime. The problem is that you have two vars responsible for deal with the selected time. The first is in your view, the seccond is in your observable object.
When the view load happens, you update the value of your observableobject, but your view value is not updated.
The solution is update only the property of your observable object and depends from that in your view. I did an example for you, I hope that it can help you.
class TimerSettings: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var selectedTime: Int?
    
    init(initialSelectedTime: Int?) {
        self.selectedTime = initialSelectedTime
    }
    func updateSelectedTime(forKey: String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedTime, forKey: forKey)
        print(time)
    }
    func loadSettings(forKey: String) {
        if let savedSettings = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: forKey) as? Int {
            selectedTime = savedSettings
            return savedSettings
        }
        selectedTime = 3
    }
}

struct TimerView: View {
    
    @StateObject var timerSettings = TimerSettings(initialSelectedTime: nil)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Настройте таймер игры:")
                .foregroundStyle(Color(.black).opacity(0.8))
            Picker("Время таймера", selection: $timerSettings.selectedTime) {
                ForEach(1..<31, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0) мин").tag($0)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            Button("Сохранить") {
                
                timerSettings.updateSelectedTime(forKey: "timerSettings")
                
            }
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .padding(.bottom, 100)
            .onAppear {
                timerSettings.loadSettings(forKey: "timerSettings")
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red:0.8980392157, green: 0.9333333333, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                CustomBackButtonView()
            }
        }
    }
}


Thank you! I tried following your example, but I got nil with fatal error in the lines:
.onAppear {
timerSettings.loadSettings(forKey: "timerSettings")!
}
I think this happened because of TimerSettings(initialSelectedTime: nil)
but I haven’t figured out how to solve it yet

First, you don't need a return in loadSettings, so you can cut it. But to ensure that you always will have a value, you can put a default value as 3.
func loadSettings(forKey: String) {
    if let savedSettings = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: forKey) as? Int {
        selectedTime = savedSettings
        return
    }
    selectedTime = 3
    return
}


I updated the code to you see it better

Hi Joao! I chose the option without a button and TimerSetting class, using AppStorage. But I still try the option you suggested and don’t understand, I write like this without return:
}
func loadSettings(forKey: String) {
if let savedSettings = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: forKey) as? Int {
selectedTime = savedSettings
}
selectedTime = 3
}
}
But if I write like this, the picker always unscrews back to 1 min

If you use @AppStorage instead you can skip the extra class.
In the view add this property
@AppStorage("timerSettings") private var timerSettings = 3

Note that 3 is the default value used if nothing is stored yet in UserDefaults
And then use this property instead in your view (I removed most of the view modifiers for clarity)
struct TimerView: View {
    @AppStorage("timerSettings") private var timerSettings = 3

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Change time:")
                .foregroundStyle(Color(.black).opacity(0.8))
            Picker("Timer", selection: $timerSettings) {
                ForEach(1..<31, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0) min").tag($0)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
        }
    }
}


Thanks! Yes it works, but I need to apply the save in the application using the button and then access to this Timer value from another view. Haven't figured it out yet

You don’t need a save button, the value is saved whenever it is changed. You use the same AppStorage property declaration in any other view where you need to access the value

So, as you wrote above, I don’t need the class and userDefaults at all in my case?

Yes that is correct
